# Even after "if" condition is met, how come "else" code is still running

Tags: python-3.x

In the below code, how come "result = n * recurse" is executed even when n==0. Shouldn't the else statement be ignored once if statement is executed. In other words, how come both the code give the same output?

My understanding is that in the first code once n==0, if condition is met so else statements won't be executed. Thus there should be no "returning 1" onwards print in the output for the first code.

```
def factorial(n):
    space = ' ' * (4 * n)
    print(space, 'factorial', n)
    if n == 0:
        print(space, 'returning 1')
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
        result = n * recurse
        print(space, 'returning', result)
        return result

def factorial(n):
    space = ' ' * (4 * n)
    print(space, 'factorial', n)
    if n == 0:
        print(space, 'returning 1')
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
    result = n * recurse
    print(space, 'returning', result)
    return result

factorial (4)



Both the codes gives the same result:
             factorial 4
         factorial 3
     factorial 2
  factorial 1
factorial 0
returning 1
 returning 1
     returning 2
         returning 6
             returning 24
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because the line in question is not in the scope of the if-else statement, see the comment in the code below:

```
def factorial(n):
    space = ' ' * (4 * n)
    print(space, 'factorial', n)
    if n == 0:
        print(space, 'returning 1')
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
    result = n * recurse # ****THIS IS OUTSIDE IF CLAUSE****
    print(space, 'returning', result)
    return result
```

Put `result = n * recurse` with the same indentation as `recurse = factorial(n-1)`, if you want it to be within else statement:

```
def factorial(n):
    space = ' ' * (4 * n)
    print(space, 'factorial', n)
    if n == 0:
        print(space, 'returning 1')
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
        result = n * recurse # ****THIS IS INSIDE IF-ELSE CLAUSE****
    print(space, 'returning', result)
    return result
```

Comment: in the first code, the indentation is same so the line is inside if-else clause. So when n=0, how come all the lines in the else block are still getting executed in the first code. I'm clear in the second code, its the first code I'm confused about. I gave both code to know why the result is same even though the indentation inside else block is different.

Comment: You need to take care to separate the two code. If you run it in a single cell in eg Jupyter Notebook, the second overwrites the first, you aware of that?

Comment: If you have a code which works then there is not much point wasting your time on a one which does not.